# Group by nearest location

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have the following table structure:

```
table `leads`:
`id` int
`postcode` varchar

table `dealers`:
`id` int
`name` varchar

table `dealer_locs`:
`id` int
`id_dealer` int (this is what links the loc to the dealer)
`postcode` varchar
`distance` int
`lat` varchar (latitude of postcode in this row)
`long` varchar (longitude of postcode in this row)
```

Each dealer can have multiple `dealer_locs` (locations). I'm trying to output a table showing the nearest dealers to a lead.

I have a function I wrote (get_lat_long()) which grabs the latitude and longitude of any postal code I want.

Consider the following code:

```
$lead['postcode'] = 'M6A 3A1';
$lat_long = get_lat_long($lead['postcode']);

$lat = $lat_long['lat'];
$long = $lat_long['long'];

$sql = mysql_query("select d.id, d.name,
                    (6371 * 3.1415926 * SQRT(($lat - dl.lat) * ($lat - dl.lat) + COS($lat / 57.2957795) * COS(dl.lat / 57.2957795) * ($long - dl.long) * ($long - dl.long)) / 180) as distance, 
                    dl.postcode as dl_postcode
                    from `dealer_locs` as dl
                    left join `dealers` as d on d.id = dl.id_dealer
                    where d.type='Real'
                    order by distance asc
                    ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Now this code does work, however it is showing duplicates since each dealer has multiple locations.

Example output from above query and code:

```
d.name        | distance
Joes Dealer   | 11
Kevins Dealer | 13
Mikes Dealer  | 21
Kevins Dealer | 43
Mikes Dealer  | 44
Joes Dealer   | 78
```

The output I want:

```
d.name        | distance
Joes Dealer   | 11
Kevins Dealer | 13
Mikes Dealer  | 21
```

My problem is I don't know how to write this group by (don't even think this needs a group by or if that is even correct practice).

Comment: you can use DISTINCT name

Comment: @AlwaysSunny it's not just getting distinct name but getting the closest dealership for each name.

Comment: BTW, don't use PHP's deprecated mysql_ API. See PDO/mysqli AND prepared statements!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
select 
    d.id, -- you can take id from here if you want
    d.name,
    min(6371 * 3.1415926 * SQRT(($lat - dl.lat) * ($lat - dl.lat) + COS($lat / 57.2957795) * COS(dl.lat / 57.2957795) * ($long - dl.long) * ($long - dl.long)) / 180) as distance, 
    dl.postcode as dl_postcode
from `dealer_locs` as dl
left join `dealers` as d on d.id = dl.id_dealer
where d.type='Real'
group by d.id
order by distance asc
```

Comment: @DionSoft added a comment to que query

Comment: What's the point of the LEFT join?  why not an inner given the where clause?  Also, what would happen if the data happened to have two different d.name's for the same D.ID?

Comment: None, just inherited it from the original query. Doesn't hurt it either in this case.

Comment: Actually wouldn't mySQL group by extensions randomly select one of the names and hide the other name from the query results for the same D.ID having different names...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 
    d.id, 
    d.name,
    (6371 * 3.1415926 * SQRT(($lat - dl.lat) * ($lat - dl.lat) + COS($lat / 57.2957795) * COS(dl.lat / 57.2957795) * ($long - dl.long) * ($long - dl.long)) / 180) as distance, 
    dl.postcode as dl_postcode
from `dealer_locs` as dl
left join `dealers` as d on d.id = dl.id_dealer
where d.type='Real' 
group by d.id 
order by distance asc
```

Comment: That won't work. The `group by` will pick a the first distance in the resultset, you need the `min()` there, or force the order before the `group by`

Comment: @MiguelRoxo,This is work well without min() . Mysql will do rest of things.

Comment: no it won't, it only works if you are lucky enough to the distance to be ordered. If you use the data of the question, it already is, may be that is why it works for you

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT d.name,
   Min(6371 * 3.1415926 * SQRT(($lat - dl.lat) * ($lat - dl.lat) + COS($lat / 57.2957795) * COS(dl.lat / 57.2957795) * ($long - dl.long) * ($long - dl.long)) / 180)) as distance, 
   dl.postcode as dl_postcode
FROM `dealer_locs` as dl
LEFT JOIN `dealers` as d 
    on d.id = dl.id_dealer
WHERE d.type='Real'
GROUP BY D.ID, D.Name
ORDER BY distance asc
```

You just need to use an aggregate (min) and group by Name.  This assumes name is unique however, otherwise you need to group by both name and ID (assuming Name could be different) or you could just group by ID and let mySQL's extended group by handle name.  (Assuming it's enabled which it is by default)

Also, it seems odd to use a LEFT Join here.  The where clause negates it making the LEFT join an INNER.

Do you need All Dealer_Locations or only those that are 'Real'?

While you asked for a LEFT outer join, due to your where clause you're getting

```
SELECT d.name,
   Min(6371 * 3.1415926 * SQRT(($lat - dl.lat) * ($lat - dl.lat) + COS($lat / 57.2957795) * COS(dl.lat / 57.2957795) * ($long - dl.long) * ($long - dl.long)) / 180)) as distance, 
   dl.postcode as dl_postcode
FROM `dealer_locs` as dl
INNER JOIN `dealers` as d 
    on d.id = dl.id_dealer
WHERE d.type='Real'
GROUP BY D.ID, D.Name
ORDER BY distance asc
```

Comment: Or you could just `group by` id and mysql will do the rest for you

Comment: Assuming that there aren't different names for the same ID.

Comment: So you preferr to assume that you can't have 2 individuals with the same name? Having 2 names for the same Id requires a very clumsy database design

Comment: That's handled by the group by.  the fact it's not in the select means the user needs to understand the data.  This separates out the data, the fact it's not rendered was due to the desired output by the OP.

Comment: Well I get your point but suppose someone is calling the dealiers based on your query. In the use case you are covering, the user would be calling 2 times the same dealer with no ideia it was the same. Even if some individual have multiple names, if it is importante you must have always some way to elect one as the default. If the purpose is to detect faulty data, you should bring Id to the `SELECT` as well

Comment: I see where your coming from as well. The problem is we don't understand the use case in full so any answer provided will have inherit risk.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the closest dealer for each name, I would wrap what you already have into a subquery and use the MIN() function to get the minimum distance when grouping by name, like this:

```
SELECT temp.name, MIN(temp.distance) AS distanceAway
FROM(SELECT d.id, d.name,
                (6371 * 3.1415926 * SQRT(($lat - dl.lat) * ($lat - dl.lat) + COS($lat / 57.2957795) * COS(dl.lat / 57.2957795) * ($long - dl.long) * ($long - dl.long)) / 180) AS distance, 
    dl.postcode AS dl_postcode
    FROM `dealer_locs` AS dl
    LEFT JOIN `dealers` AS d ON d.id = dl.id_dealer
    WHERE d.type = 'Real') temp
GROUP BY temp.name
ORDER BY distanceAway;
```

Note that I moved order by to the outside to order the final results. I also just came up with 'distanceAway' instead of distance to avoid ambiguity. You can change columns names to fit what you want.

Comment: The inner query gives you no advantage

Comment: There is no reason for having an inner query and the `group by` and `order by` outside

Comment: I guess not, but it's not incorrect. It just made sense to me that way because OP already had a working result set, so I took the approach of manipulating his result set to get what he wants. Either solution works though.